# Flask-Babel how to use translation in Jinja template file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, gettext, flask-babel

In my Flask application, in main.py file, I defined:

```
from flaskext.babel import gettext
....
def somefun():
    return render_template('some.html', messages=messages)
```

in template file some.html, I used:

```
<input type='text' name='keywords' value='{{ keywords|default('') }}' placeholder='{{ gettext('Search...') }}' />
```

This gives an error:

```
<input type='text' name='keywords' value='{{ keywords|default('') }}' placeholder='{{ gettext('Search...') }}' />
UndefinedError: 'gettext' is undefined
```

How to import this function for template use?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not documented at all, but Flask-Babel is transparently using [Jinja2's i18n extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#i18n-in-templates). This means that by default, following functions for expressions are available: `gettext`, `ngettext` and `_`.

There's also possibility to use template tags:

```
{% trans %}foo{% endtrans%}

{% trans num %}
There is {{ num }} object.
{% pluralize %}
There are {{ num }} objects.
{% endtrans %}
```

And the [bug report about missing docs](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/issues/1) that's waiting for patches ;)

Comment: it's not true, I can't use "_" without any importing actions.

Comment: @BrentJiang Did you actually init the Flask-Babel extension?

Comment: thanks, it works after create 'from flaskext.babel import Babel' and 'babel = Babel(app)'

Comment: you are a life saver

Comment: I needed `{% trans with name=varFromContext %}Hello {{ name }}{% endtrans %}`

Comment: https://support.sendwithus.com/templating/translating_templates/